# how to pass variable from nodejs to html directly without using pug?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I need to pass a variable from a NodeJS file to a rendered html file. How to do that?

Here below what I had tried

Nodejs code

```
const loginRouter= express.Router();

const config= require('../config/config.json');

loginRouter.get('/', (req,res)=>{

    res.render(path.dirname(__dirname)+'/views/login.html',{version:config.version});

    //res.json('done')
});
```

HTML Code

```
<label style="font-size:10px;float: right;"><%= version %></label>
```

Current Result:-
Nothing is coming

Expected Result:-

```
<label style="font-size:10px;float: right;">3.9</label>
```

I have set this version number in my config which I have imported in my login.js, but still, I am not getting the output. Does anyone have any idea about it?

Comment: Try `console.log()` your variable if its empty? in your route

Comment: use ejs or something like it to render your pages https://www.npmjs.com/package/ejs

Comment: I can add an example if you want, just try it if you can

Comment: @jank i tried this way also 
<script>var name = "<%= name %>";</script>
console.log(name);
but i am not getting

Comment: @Ganesh Karewad  please add an example

Comment: Either use a templating engine, or use requests (Ajax, websockets, SSE, etc...)

Comment: Are you using a view engine in your server? set the view engine to ejs
`app.set('view engine', 'ejs');`

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use a templating engine like *ejs* or *pug* then you can just send a get request with `axios` or `fetch` to your node server and send a response.

Here's a sample on how you can do it. Change it according to your needs.

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 id="title">My page</h1>
    <script>
        fetch('http://localhost:5000/version').then(function(response) {
            return response.json();
        }).then(function(myJson) {
            document.getElementById('title').innerHTML = myJson;
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**server.js**

```
const express = require('express');

const app = express();

const PORT = 5000;

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile('index.html', {root: __dirname });
});

app.get('/version', (req, res) => {
    const myVersion = 'My version is 0.5';
    res.json(myVersion);
});

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server running on PORT ${PORT}`);
});
```

Comment: well one thing worked
loginRouter.get('/', (req,res)=>{
    res.render(path.dirname(__dirname)+'/views/login.html',{version_no:config.version_number})
});

HTML
<label class="version" id="version_no"><%= version_no %></label>

Comment: Every body is missing the closing percentile, nothing else opening closing percentile will make your code work

Comment: I am sorry, I couldn't get you. Are you now getting the variable value in your html?

Comment: <%= version_no %> this will get you the variable if you are passing from node js file

Comment: Okay if your problem is solved then consider upvoting and accepting the answer if it was helpful or let me know if you are getting any other errors.

Comment: ya I will post the issues